# Postgres/Mysql Mudar o dado de um campo que se repete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql

Bom dia tenho a tabela "areas",
Nela tenho a coluna "f_name"

Quero transformar a coluna "f_name" para unique id.
Porém, há dados repetidos atualmente.

Eu preciso de um comando Sql onde faça uma varredura nesta coluna e quando encontrar repetido altere para o dado atual seguido do caracter 2.
Exemplo:

**Andre Machado** -> altera para **Andre Machado2**

O código unique Id eu já tenho, irei aplicar logo após a alteração:

```
ALTER TABLE areas ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (f_name);
```

Obs. Devido a complexibilidade, é aceito também o resultado alterando todos aqueles que forem repetidos para um número alteatório no final. Exemplo: "André Machado 8989", e "André Machado 7436", sem fazer diferença entre o dado do primeiro campo e o dado do segundo campo, facilitando.

Imagino que seria um sql parecido:

> update table set f_name = f_name || ' ' || rand(1111,9999) where
>   count(f_name) = 2

Preciso para postgres, mas pode ser em mysql!

Comment: Êta gambiarra! Não seria melhor corrigir o sistema e alterar os dados incorretos já cadastrados para o valor correto?

Comment: O meu cenário teria melhor resultado com o código em sql antes de aplicar a constrant de unique id. Mas entendo sua sugestão, seria uma opção.

Comment: Para o PostgreSQL você pode desenvolver um procedimento em PL/pgSQL onde faça um loop: FOR target IN query LOOP
    statements
END LOOP; e vá incrementando uma variável auxiliar e executando um comando dinâmico para cada update. Consulte a documentação. Em seu exemplo note que nada impede que a função rand repita um número no intervalo e, creio, você deveria utilizar a cláusula HAVING e não a WHERE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tente isso:**

```
update 
Table 
set 
f_name = f_name || f_id 
where f_name in
(SELECT f_name FROM table  GROUP BY f_name HAVING COUNT(f_name) > 1);
```

Não é a melhor solução, pois pega todos registros, inclusive o primeiro, mas vai conseguir destravar o Sprint.